# Почему после слова "лес" запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

На одном сообществе нашла вот такое вот предложение, где расстановка запятых признана правильной:

[image: img]

"Вижу лес, и вечернее полымя, и обвитый крапивой плетень". Все хорошо, но я не понимаю, почему запятая стоит после слова "лес". Поясните, пожалуйста!

Comment: Чот подумалось... А откуда эта фраза?!
При некотором желании её можно написать и без запятых вовсе.
Если сгруппировать лес и полымя как бы на нижнем уровне, а плетень - на верхнем. Тогда наши И будут не повторяющимся союзом, а двумя одиночными. Вот безусловный пример такого: *на столе лежали сливы, яблоки и груши и забытая кем-то газета*. Вряд ли кому придёт в голову требовать запятых перед И. А теперь уберем "сливы" вместе с заяпой. Получим наш случай...

Comment: ЗЫ А вообще - спасибо за розыгрыш. )))
Неплохо копья поломали на пустом месте. )))
Черт, а ведь неплохо когда-то знал Есенина... Посмотрите в бумажном издании, у кого есть под рукой, "За горами, за жёлтыми долами", 1916. Там тоже нет первой запятой?!

Comment: Кто бы все-таки объяснил, почему у автора запятой нет.

Comment: Значит автор  объединял лес и полымя в смысловое единство (в пару). Стихотворение можно прочесть по-разному. При такой пунктуации не нужна перечислительная интонация при первых однородных членах. Знаки препинания помогают понять авторское видение пейзажа. Не знаю, правда. как у Есенина в действительности стояли знаки. Яндекс выдает оба варианта. Без запятой - преимущественно.

Comment: Почему же... Если рассматривать  И не как соединительный, а как присоединительный

Comment: Ларf, мне пришлось удалить предыдущий коммент, чтобы задать вопрос. 
Мне понравилась идея про присоединительный союз, но на основании чего иы модем рассматривать его как таковой?  
Или, с другой стороны, что тогда мешает нам любое И между даже двумя однородными считать присоединительным?  

Только не убегайте, пожалуйста. Эти вопросы - проявление заинтересованности, а не недоверия к Вам.

Comment: Картинка похожа на те, которые публикует сообщество "Я люблю русский язык" ВКонтакте. Меня там забанили из-за того, что я им указывал им на их ошибки. Автор паблика — школьник, любящий, но не знающий русский язык. Не стоит ему доверять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Розенталя есть более понятное и простое правило: При наличии однородных членов, связанных повторяющимися союзами, запятая ставится перед первым из повторяющихся союзов, если перечисление однородных членов началось до первого из повторяющихся союзов

Comment: 'Я увидел и лес, и полымя, и плетень. Здесь не нужны запятые? Почему.

 "" Запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством повторяющихся союзов и... и, да... да, ни... ни, или... или, либо... либо, то... то и другие: Темнота раннего зимнего утра скрывала и площадку на берегу, и полотняный поселок из палаток, и самих побей; Ни справа, ни слева, ни на воде, ни на берегу никого не было; Или погибнуть, или завоевать себе право устроить жизнь по правде - так был поставлен вопрос. ""

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что оно "более понятное". Запятая ставится не "перед первым", а "перед всеми".

Comment: Запятая перед остальными повторяющимися союзами - это уж само собой разумеется

Comment: Если всё само собой разумеется, зачем тогда правила формулировать?!

Answer (score 5):

Если число однородных членов больше двух, а союз повторяется ***перед каждым из них, кроме первого***, то запятая ставится **между ними всеми**, например: ***А вокруг были дым, и бой, и смерть (Горбатов); Иные хозяева вырастили уже вишни, или сирень, или жасмин (Фадеев); Только мальвы, да ноготки, да крученый паныч цвели кое-где по дорогам*** (В. Панова).[Розенталь](http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/43.htm#з_05)

Answer (score 3):

Все просто. Однородные члены разделяются запятой. Запятая не ставится только если однородные члены соединяются одиночным союзом И и ИЛИ. А здесь союз повторяющийся.  Вижу лес, и полымя, и плетень.

Comment: Ответ Лораны понятен и прост, я это правило со школы помню и никогда в подобных случаях не ошибаюсь. Вызывает недоумение, почему за этот ответ кто-то минус поставил? А вот в "простое правило Розенталя" я, ей-богу, не врубился.

Answer (score 2):

Дети, которых я беру учить только в 10-11 кл., часто удивляются: ведь перед первой и, говорят, запятая не ставится. Причина заблуждения - непонимание основного принципа: *однородные члены надо разделить запятой, т.е. поставить запятую **между** однородными членами.* Кроме случаев, когда союз и (или) одиночный. Так что я вполне согласна с Лораной. Большое правило о знаках препинания при однородных членах сводится к пониманию главного. А дальше применяйте это правило к любым случаям.

Comment: Ларf, Вы полагаете, "главное" - это запятая перед первым И? 
Иначе логику "пойми частный случай правила" я объяснить не могу. 

Причина же заблуждения мне хорошо понятна. Слишком много внимания уделяют случаю, когда "повторяющийся" союз предшествует **всем**, в том числе и первому (И петя, и Миша, и Вася) и тоже формулируют куцее правило, сводящееся к тому, что *перед первым* союзом запятая не ставится. Детишки переносят это и на наш случай. Не мудрено, с такими-то формулировками...

Comment: Формулировка же "**перед** первым союзом" отнюдь не противоречит тому, что запятые ставятся **меджду** однородными. Наоборот, показывает, что союз как бы относится ко чторому из однородных. А то ведь можно и *после* союза влепить. Так что ответ Лораны вполне правильный, но уж восторгов по поводу формулировки еникак не могу разделить. Она куцая.

Comment: читайте ответ внимательно!

Comment: Вы с кем разговариваете? Если со мной, то спасибо за идею.

Answer (score 0):

Проще объяснить с помощью схемы, где однородные члены обозначаются кружочками:О,и О,и О Если перед союзом есть кружочек, значит, запятая нужна. А если нет, то не нужна:и О,и О Пятклассники так запоминают.